# Expected overlap of two samples from a multivariate normal vector

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, linear

Suppose $\mathbf x$ is a normally distributed vector, with means $\mathbf{u}$ and covariance matrix $\mathbb C$. Suppose I draw two independent samples from this distribution, $\mathbf{x}^{1},\mathbf{x}^{2}$. I'm interested in the statistics of the overlap:

$$\phi = \frac{(\mathbf{x}^1)^\top(\mathbf{x}^2)}{\sqrt{((\mathbf{x}^1)^\top(\mathbf{x}^1))((\mathbf{x}^2)^\top(\mathbf{x}^2))}}$$

and how these statistics depend on $\mathbf u$, $\mathbb C$. In particular, I would like to be able to compute the mean:

$$\langle\phi\rangle$$

and maybe also (I'm not sure if this is feasible), the variance:

$$\mathrm{var}(\phi)$$

Comment: What do you mean by *overlap*?  What is the goal, its use¡

Comment: I defined overlap in the question, $\phi$. @kjetilbhalvorsen, not sure what you're asking?

Comment: What is *overlap* intended to indicate? If vectors where centered it would be a correlation, yes. What is the intended use of overlap, and why the name? Is this an established concept? if so, a reference?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Ah you are questioning the use of the word "overlap" here? Okay, I've seen it under that name in statistical physics of learning related papers (see for instance https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/madvani/files/repcavmes6.pdf). But please if you have a better name suggest it!